# when I click label of input type="checkbox" first status "false"

Tags: checkbox, label

```js
if(clickEl.parentNode.querySelector('input').checked === true) {
  console.log(555);
} else {
  console.log(111);
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown-category-list__list" data-filter="sneakers">
  <input type="checkbox" id="filterSneakers">
  <label for="filterSneakers">Sneakers</label>
</li>
```

When I click on input everything works fine, result = 555,111,555,111 and so on
But when I click label result 111,555,555,111,111,555,555,111 and it is wrong behaviour

I know that I can wrap input into label but how to fix it withour editing html structure

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is in your implementation. Everything work as expected

```js
document.querySelector('input').onchange = function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown-category-list__list" data-filter="sneakers">
  <input type="checkbox" id="filterSneakers">
  <label for="filterSneakers">Sneakers</label>
</li>
```